# Using Mockito WhiteBox for setting a member variable inside a method scope

Tags: junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito and is trying to figure out whether there is a way to set the value of a member variable inside a public method using WhiteBox features of Mockito.

I tried searching for this but seems no references are talking about this.

Is it doable or not.

Thanks

Added an example of what I want to achieve. Consider the following class.

```
public class FinancialsCalculator {
    private int va11;
    private int val2; 

    public int calculateFinancialsAppliedSum() {
        //In actual application this calc get's Injected using Guice
        Calculator calc;

        //Some pre-processing to the values val1 and val2 will be performed here

        return calc.getSum(val1, val2);
    }
}
```

Now I need to unit test the above class. And I want to mock the Calculator class instance inside the scope of the calculateFinancialsAppliedSum method.

If it was in the FinancialsCalculator class level (i.e. in the same level as val1 and val2 variables), I could have mocked it easily and use Whitebox.setInternalState() of mockito to set the mocked instance to that class level private instance of Calculator.

Unfortunately due to other reasons, I cannot make this Calculator instance a class level private instance of FinancialsCalculator class. It has to be within the calculateFinancialsAppliedSum method.

So how can I mock this Calculator instance inside the calculateFinancialsAppliedSum method for testing?

Comment: "inside a public method" doesn't seem clear to me. Can you please add an example, or demonstrate a `HypotheticalWhitebox` that does what you want?

Comment: @JeffBowman added an example of what I want to achieve

Comment: Whitebox is part of PowerMock and not Mockito.

Comment: How is the Calculator injected? Field injection, setter injection, constructor injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this as you described; WhiteBox and similar tools can change the value of an instance's field, because it is persistent, but a method variable exists on the stack only while the method is being executed and thus there's no way to access or reset it from outside the method.

Because Calculator is being injected through Guice, there is likely a good injection point (method, field, or constructor) that you can call yourself in the test to insert your Calculator mock.

You could also refactor to make testing easier:

```
public class FinancialsCalculator {
    private int va11;
    private int val2; 

    public int calculateFinancialsAppliedSum() {
        return calculateFinancialsAppliedSum(calc);
    }

    /** Uses the passed Calculator. Call only from tests. */
    @VisibleForTesting int calculateFinancialsAppliedSum(Calculator calc) {
        //Some pre-processing to the values val1 and val2 will be performed here
        return calc.getSum(val1, val2);
    }
}
```

Or even make the method static so it can be tested with completely arbitrary values:

```
public class FinancialsCalculator {
    private int va11;
    private int val2; 

    public int calculateFinancialsAppliedSum() {
        return calculateFinancialsAppliedSum(calc, val1, val2);
    }

    /** Uses the passed Calculator, val1, and val2. Call only from tests. */
    @VisibleForTesting static int calculateFinancialsAppliedSum(
            Calculator calc, int val1, int val2) {
        //Some pre-processing to the values val1 and val2 will be performed here
        return calc.getSum(val1, val2);
    }
}
```